# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: WHERE Clause

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database. However, it gives me an error of:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE FORMID = 120002013 AND CLASSIFICATION = 'Private'' at line 1
```

Below is my code for retrieving data:

```
try (Connection conn = myFactory.getConnection()) {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT CENSUSYEAR, SCHOOLID, CLASSIFICATION, SCHOOLNAME" +
    "FROM DIRECTORY_SCHOOL WHERE FORMID = ? AND CLASSIFICATION = ?");
    pstmt.setInt(1, formID);
    pstmt.setString(2, classification);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you need a space in front of your `from` clause -- currently you are writing `select ... schoolnamefrom directory_school where...`

Comment: Try printing your SQL query. Pay attention to result of  `SCHOOLNAME"+"FROM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SCHOOLNAME"+"FROM" makes it SCHOOLNAMEFROM